# NEON implementation in ARM

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I am a beginner in NEON and wanted to optimize the following code but while it compiles and produces the same output as desired , I don't see any improvement. AFAIK NEON is helpful in doing operations on contiguous block of data so I was hoping some improvement in execution time and cycles.What am i doing wrong??

I'm working on  gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 with -03 level optimization

normal c implementation

```
for(i= 0;i<9215;i++)
            {
                Z[i] = (L[i]>0)?0:1;    
            }
```

Neon form

```
for(i=0;i<9215;i+=4)
{                                                                                   
             int32x4_t l_N = vld1q_s32(&L[i]);
            uint32x4_t mask_n=vcltq_s32(l_N,zero_N);
             int32x4_t z_n = vbslq_s32(mask_n,one_N,zero_N);
             vst1q_s32(&Z[i],z_n);

}
```

Comment: It's almost a miracle that your routine doesn't cause an exception. 9215 isn't a multiple of 4.

Comment: And the computation part isn't efficient either: `vbsl` is a rather expensive instruction. You can do a saturating subtraction by one(`vqsub`), typecast to unsigned, then shift by 31 (`vshr_u32`).

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

- You are using a very inefficient algorithm for the computation inside the loop
- Your routine suffers from heavy pipeline interlocks, instruction by instruction

---

```
void isNonNatural(int32_t * pDst, int32_t *pSrc, int n)
{
    int32x4_t vec;
    const int32x4_t one = vdupq_n_s32(1);
    int32_t a;

    unsigned int i;

    if (n >= 4)
    {
        n -= 4;
        while (1) {
            do {
                n -= 4;
                vec = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
                vec = vqsubq_s32(vec, one);
                vec = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec, 31);
                vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec);
            } while (n >= 0);

            if (n <= -4) return;

            // dealing with residuals

            pSrc += n;  // rewind pointers
            pDst += n;
        } // iterate for one last time
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a = *pSrc++;
        if (a > 0) a = 0; else a = 1;
        *pDst++ = a;
    }
}
```

This function above should be somewhat faster than your implementation.

- a saturating subtraction by 1 is done so that 0 becomes -1 while 0x80000000 remains 0x80000000
- The elements get shifted by 31 bits so that only the sign bit remains.
- I you can live with 0xffffffff instead of 1, you can leave out the typecasting and use `vshrq_n_s32` instead. It won't be any faster though.
- Pay attention to the residual management.

---

Programming NEON is like driving a big truck. You shouldn't drive it like a compact car.

While NEON can compute multiple data at once, mostly in a single cycle, it has higher instruction latencies, usually 3~4 cycles. In other words, each and every instruction has to wait that long for the previous one to return the result in the implementation above.

Virtually the only way avoiding this is unrolling, a deep one.

```
void isNonNatural_unroll(int32_t * pDst, int32_t *pSrc, int n)
{
    int32x4_t vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4;
    const int32x4_t one = vdupq_n_s32(1);
    int32_t a;

    unsigned int i;

    if (n >= 16)
    {
        n -= 16;
        while (1) {
            do {
                n -= 16;
                vec1 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
                vec2 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
                vec3 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
                vec4 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
                vec1 = vqsubq_s32(vec1, one);
                vec2 = vqsubq_s32(vec2, one);
                vec3 = vqsubq_s32(vec3, one);
                vec4 = vqsubq_s32(vec4, one);
                vec1 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec1, 31);
                vec2 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec2, 31);
                vec3 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec3, 31);
                vec4 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec4, 31);
                vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec1);
                vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec2);
                vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec3);
                vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec4);
            } while (n >= 0);

            if (n <= -16) return;

            // dealing with residuals

            pSrc += n;  // rewind pointers
            pDst += n;
        } // iterate for one last time
    }

    if (n & 8)
    {
        vec1 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
        vec2 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
        vec1 = vqsubq_s32(vec1, one);
        vec2 = vqsubq_s32(vec2, one);
        vec1 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec1, 31);
        vec2 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec2, 31);
        vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec1);
        vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec2);
    }

    if (n & 4)
    {
        vec1 = vld1q_s32(pSrc++);
        vec1 = vqsubq_s32(vec1, one);
        vec1 = (int32x4_t) vshrq_n_u32((uint32x4_t) vec1, 31);
        vst1q_s32(pDst++, vec1);
    }

    n &= 3;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a = *pSrc++;
        if (a > 0) a = 0; else a = 1;
        *pDst++ = a;
    }
}
```

Now this one should be a lot faster than the previous ones since virtually all the latencies are hidden (more than four times as fast), provided the pathetic compilers don't mess it up.

Comment: thank you so much for your input ,it took me 2 hours to understand your implementation but finally i did understand and implemented it in my code with changes but it increased the cycles drastically, and i apologize for giving the index as 9215 which was actually 9216

Comment: plus 1 for acknowledging how compilers mess up perfectly good intrinsics :)

Comment: yes , @BitBank I think you are right ,but right now I cant change my compiler.

Comment: @Skynet I'm willing to provide you a fully optimized assembly version (which is my specialty), both for `aarch32` and `aarch64`. Would you post the benchmark results then?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE thank you so much for the help but I'm currently bound by some constraints where i can not use assembly language as but i tried inline assembly and it worked for very simple things like floating to fixed conversion so yeah I will give benchmarks for sure.